# I want to create a jQuery loop out of this function instead of copying this function over and over for 12 times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, loops

I need some help with creating a loop in this jQuery function. I have some elements on my HTML page with the attribute `[level-data="l1"]`, and I use them in my function to make some changes on the page. I have 12 different attributes starting with the `[level-data="l1"]` and finishing with the `[level-data="l12"]`. What I want is to create a jQuery loop instead of copying this function over and over for 12 times, each element will have a different `[level-data='ln']` attribute, where n is a number from 1 to 12.
Here is my code:

```
$('.chart-level[level-data="l1"]').on("click", function () {
        
        $('.chart-level').removeClass('active');
        $('.chart-levels-items .level-info').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        
        $('.chart-levels-items .level-info[level-data="l1"]').addClass('active'); 
        
        $('.chart-slider-item.page_slider').removeClass('shown');
        $('.chart-slider-item.page_slider[level-data="l1"]').addClass('shown');
        
        $('.chart-slider-item.popup_slider').removeClass('shown');
        $('.chart-slider-item.popup_slider[level-data="l1"]').addClass('shown');
        
        if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches){
            $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $(".chart-levels-items .level-info[level-data='l1']").offset().top
    }, 2000);
        }
    });
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need a loop. Use `.chart-level[level-data]` as the selector and read the `level-data` attribute of the clicked element (the attribute should be `data-level`? Then you can use `$(this).data('level')` for reading the value.)

Comment: sorry, I'm a beginner, I didn't really get it, could you please  be so kind to provide a code example?

Comment: For sure! Can you update your question with the related html so I'll be able to change the selectors accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop. Use `.chart-level[level-data]` as the selector and read the `level-data` attribute of the clicked element. `[...]` is an attribute selector which selects elements that *have a certain attribute*.

Note that `level-data` is an invalid attribute. You can use `data-*` attributes instead. i.e. change it to `data-level`. Then you can use `$(this).data('level')` for reading the value of the `data-level` attribute.

```
$('.chart-level[data-level]').on("click", function () {
    var level = $(this).data('level')        
    $('.chart-levels-items .level-info[data-level="' + level + '"]').addClass('active');
    // ...
});
```

In case that you are using the attribute just for selecting related elements to the clicked element, then you should consider using jQuery traversal methods (like `parent`, `siblings`, ...) for selecting the target elements instead.